# Get relative path of a File path?

Tags: java, file, path, relative-path, java-7

I need to get the relative file path (relative to the program executable path) from a `File` object.

What's the best way to do this? `File` offers only methods for the absolute path. Maybe getting execution path manually and then cut this path off from the absolute path to get a relative path?

I am on Java 7, just in case java.nio has some helping method for that.

Tahnks for any hint!

Comment: You have a design Problem, just use "." as the path of the excutable, and refere from there relative, or absoulte.

Comment: The `URI` type can be used for this.

Answer (score 4):

As you're using Java 7 you can make use of the new Path class, which has a number of really cool methods, including [Path.relativize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

Answer (score 3):

You need the method:

```
Path relativize(Path other)
```

of `java.nio.file.Path`.

To obtain a Path from a file you could use its `Path toPath()` method.

Comment: such a cool name for such a useful method